# Table function with Part[] call misbehaving, but only after initial startup of Mathematica

Tags: warning-messages, kernel-startup

I am getting errors like:

```
Part::partd: 
   Part specification standardBasis[[1]] is longer than depth of object.
```

with the following Manipulate expression:

```
Clear[  e1, e2, standardBasis, y]
e1 := {1, 0}
e2 := {0, 1}
standardBasis := {e1, e2}
y := 3
Manipulate[
 p := {x, y} ;
 Clear[j];
 arrowsReference = Table[Arrow[{p, p + Part[standardBasis, j]}], {j, 2}]
 , {{x, 1}, -10, 10} ]
```

The odd thing about it is that this only occurs immediately after starting Mathematica, on the source file that contains this manipulate.  A second shift-enter on the expression after that works without complaint and I get the desired result.

This appears to be related to the startup of mathematica using specific notebooks.  The sequence I'm using is:

- go to windows explorer.
- double click on a .nb or .cdf file with this source.
- click enable-dynamics.
- get the error.
- shift-enter: error goes away.

whereas if I take a notebook that is blank and already opened and then cut and paste this source into it, I don't get any errors about the `Part[]` expressions.

Comment: Are you sure you want the Clear[j] in your `Manipulate`. Doesn't seem to make sense here.

Comment: I'd tried it as an experiment ... it didn't help and I forgot to remove it.  I suspect that j in such an expression is local anyways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to deal with problems like this is to use `DynamicModule` inside the `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
  DynamicModule[{e1, e2, standardBasis, y, p}
  , e1 := {1, 0}
  ; e2 := {0, 1}
  ; standardBasis := {e1, e2}
  ; y := 3
  ; Dynamic[
      p := {x, y}
    ; arrowsReference =
        Table[Arrow[{p, p + Part[standardBasis, j]}], {j, 2}]
    ]
  ]
  , {{x, 1}, -10, 10}
]
```

The example localizes all of the symbols except `arrowsReference`.  In the original example, it seemed like `arrowsReference` was meant to "escape" the `Manipulate`.  Adjust these decisions to meet your needs.

The expressions that initialize `e1`, `e2`, `standardBasis` and `y` will each be evaluated exactly once (each session) as the `Manipulate` is initialized.  Only the contents of the `Dynamic` expression will be re-evaluated each time the controls are manipulated.

This approach saves the state of the localized variables across Mathematica front-end sessions.  Also, the output cell can be copied and pasted to create a new independent cell with its own state -- a desirable attribute when creating CDFs and demonstrations.

All this works because of the unusual evaluation sequence documented under the *More Information* section of [DynamicModule](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicModule.html).  Essentially, there is a kind of "double evaluation" at work.  The initial definitions (`e1 := ...` through `Dynamic[...]`) are evaluated in the first pass as if they were defined within a `Module`.  Then, the final result (in this case `Dynamic[...]`) is wrapped into a new `DynamicModule` and that becomes the content of the the `Manipulate`.

Comment: What are your thoughts on putting DynamicModule outside of Manipulate versus inside? (+1)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think it is somewhat arbitrary.  I tend to put it outside myself.  But I've answered quite a few questions on this topic in the context of a Wolfram Demonstration (as I know you have) so I put it inside the Manipulate as a reflex.

Answer (score 10):

I assume this is caused by the dynamic content becoming active and trying to run its internal code involving standardBasis which is at that moment undefined (and you can't do a `Part`on an undefined variable). You may add `SaveDefinitions->True` to your manipulate to store definitions it depends on.

`SaveDefinitions` has the disadvantage that it may cause external [definitions to be made inadvertently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579644/savedefinitions-considered-dangerous) if you don't take care.

Comment: I usually just click "disable dynamic updating" until I can evaluate all relevant definitions.  Then I just re-enable dynamic updating from the Evaluation menu.