# How to identify chemical substance from tattoo?

Tags: image-processing, image, curated-data, chemistry, ocr

A friend of mine made a tattoo on his chest of some chemical substance formula.

He challenged us to identify which substance is that. I thought that perhaps a combination of:

- Mathematica image processing capabilities
- Wolfram|Alpha chemical data
- Manual intervention

could do the trick. Here is the picture:

[image]

I am looking for pointers on how to attack the problem (like keywords of Mathematica functions, etc).

**EDIT 1**: I suppose the following need to be done:

- Extract the formula from the picture as basic (2D) structure diagram
- Define a distance metric for images or use existing one (e.g., `ImageDistance[]`)
- Calculate the distance of our element's diagram against all `ChemicalData[]` elements
- Pick the few first and do a visual verification

At the moment 1st step seems like the most challenging.

**EDIT 2**: As shown by Sjoerd it is much easier to search for a formula as string rather than as image!

Comment: Anyone know a quick way to import all chemical data?
I ran `ChemicalData/@ChemicalData[]` but it connects to wolfram servers once for each entry, so some 40k times. Had to quit the kernel to get it to stop. (v8)

Comment: @ssch Perhaps this is useful? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3549/how-to-save-chemicaldata-queries-so-that-they-are-available-immediately-on-noteb

Comment: I don't want to be a party pooper, so here's the [spoiler alert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testosterone).

Comment: All I can say is drat - why was I giving a lecture when this question showed up?!?!?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Preload all chemical data:

```
ChemicalData[All, "Preload"];
RebuildPacletData[]; (* the latter should not really be necessary *)
```

Get all names:

```
cd = ChemicalData[];
```

Get their molecular formulae:

```
l = ChemicalData[#, "MolecularFormulaString"] & /@ cd;
```

By counting the Cs, Os and Hs in the tattooed diagram we know we have to find $\rm{C_{19}H_{28}O_{2}}$. Looking for all molecules that have that molecular formula:

```
p = Position[l, "C19H28O2"];

Column[Labeled[ChemicalData[#, "StructureDiagram"], #] & /@ Extract[cd, p]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looks like it is Testosterone.

---

### UPDATE

---

In 10.4 one can call various external services dealing with chemical and/or pharmaceutical data, such as PubChem, ChemSpider and OpenPHACTS. If one knows how to code the chemical diagram into a [SMILES string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system) this gives an alternative approach to identifying this compound:

```
pubchem = ServiceConnect["PubChem"];

pubchem[
  "CompoundSynonyms", 
  {"SMILES" -> "CC12CCC3C(C1CCC2O)CCC4=CC(=O)CCC34C"}
][1, "Synonym"] //Normal // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Among all the synonyms we see **testosterone** pop up.

Comment: Nicely done Sjoerd! Searching for a formula as string is much easier than as image!

Comment: @zet My pleasure. It took me a bit longer than necessary because I initially miscounted the number of Hs.

Comment: Nice solution, +1! It also thins down results if you have some additional chemistry knowledge, like the molecule has sterol structure (name should include "ster"), an alcohol (with a hydroxyl group -OH), with a carbonyl group at the other end (-C=0), i.e. it is also a ketone (name should end with "-one"). The friend's gender helps to figure out the "testo-" part...

Comment: I will leave the question open for a couple of days and then I'll accept your answer @SjoerdC.deVries. Thanks again.

Comment: @zet no problem.