# Something wrong with the way units are handled in V10

Tags: version-10, curated-data, units

(This applies only to version 10)

I obtain these two properties of silicon:

```
a = ElementData[14, "CrustAbundance"]
b = ElementData[14, "MeteoriteAbundance"]
```

both are given in units of `g/g`. Then I divide these two values

```
a/b
```

and get an odd result, which with I cannot further reasonably calculate with or plot.

```
(Quantity[0.000034, ("Grams")/("Grams")]) Quantity[3.6*10^6, (1/#1 &)[("Grams")/("Grams")]]
```

Comment: both in V9 and WolframAlpha, I get a dimensionless number.

Comment: Yep, you only get units in V10. I should have added this: only in V10.

Comment: @MockupDungeon Well, just click the edit link and add it than (you can also add the correct tag).

Comment: OK, done, incl. tag.

Comment: As a workaround, since you know that the "Grams"/"Grams" should provide a dimensionless value, use QuantityMagnitude. `a = ElementData[14, "CrustAbundance"] // QuantityMagnitude; b = ElementData[14, "MeteoriteAbundance"] // QuantityMagnitude; a/b` gives `1.9`.

Comment: @BobHanlon OK, yes that works, but it still seems something is wrong with the data from Wolfram.

Comment: That's why I called it a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely bad behavior in the units code; here's the simpler version:

```
In[12]:= Power[Quantity[2, "Grams"/"Grams"], -1]
Out[12]= Quantity[1/2, (1/#1 &)[("Grams")/("Grams")]]
```

I've already sent a report to developers about this, but as an additional work-around you can use `UnitSimplify` on the results from `ElementData` to get the simpler(nondimensional) form:

```
In[17]:= UnitSimplify[ElementData[14, "CrustAbundance"]]
Out[17]= 0.27
```

and `UnitSimplify` won't remove quantity expressions if the units still belong:

```
In[19]:= UnitSimplify[ElementData[14, "VickersHardness"]]
Out[19]= Quantity[9.63*10^3, "Megapascals"]
```

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, units provided by the curated data sets aren't quite ready prime time, and therefore I use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56174/7167) answer to shut them off.

```
SetSystemOptions[SystemOptions["DataOptions"] /. True -> False]

a = ElementData[14, "CrustAbundance"]
b = ElementData[14, "MeteoriteAbundance"]
a/b
(* 0.27, 0.14, 2 *)
```