# How to cache a paclet permanently?

Tags: curated-data, paclets

I have needed to use a paclet when I did not have internet and was out of luck. ***Is there some way to tell Mathematica to cache and never re-download a list of certain paclets?***

[image: example]

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78954)

Comment: @J.M. Wouldn't this indeed be a duplicate of either [(3549)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3549/121) or [(78954)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78954/121)?

Comment: I guess, @Mr. Wizard.

Comment: Perhaps someone can summarize the answer then for GraphData in V11?

Comment: @M.R. if you look at the `GraphData` dvs they're missing the `"Preload"` and `"Install"` commands that `ChemicalData` has. Rather you'll need to use ``DataPaclets`GraphDataDump`MyGraphData[___, "Preload"]``