# Use 'ThermodynamicData' offline?

Tags: curated-data

Is there any possibility to use the 'ThermodynamicData' function without accessing the Internet?

I tried to run a script on a computer without access to the Internet, and i found that the function 'ThermodynamicData' couldn't be run offline.

The 'ThermodynamicData' function is a very convenient tool, but requiring the Internet access for its usage somehow limits its applicability and increases its time consumption. I am wondering if there is a way like downloading packages so that it can be called offline.

Comment: Just noting that [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3551/12) does *not* work with `ThermodynamicData`.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to use `ThermodynamicData` without an internet connection.