# Syntax highlighter shows error for Manipulate when it's inside a Block or a Module

Tags: front-end, dynamic, scoping, version-10

I'm putting my new copy of Mathematica 10 through its paces and I noticed a weird change in the colouring scheme that I find very annoying, and I'd like to get some insight into why it's happening.

The change happens, as far as I can tell, for variables that have been set in some scoping construct which are then used inside of a Manipulate command. Thus, for example, the code

```
Module[
 {A = 1},
 Manipulate[
  Plot[
   A Sin[k x]
   , {x, 0, 20}
   ]
  , {k, 1, 10}
  ]
 ]
```

renders differently in the Mathematica 9 and 10 frontends:

[image]

Playing around in Edit > Preferences > Appearance > Syntax Coloring > Errors and Warnings, the error class that this is attributed to is

> Variables that will go out of scope before being used

though what that means exactly isn't very clear to me. Therefore, I have some questions:

- Is this in fact an incorrect usage? If so, why, and what alternative construct should I use? (I notice, in particular, that in version 10 the red colour is displayed for Block and Module but not for With.)
- Why did this only start happening in version 10? Which version is right?
- If this sort of code is OK, can I safely disable this sort of error marking? What risks does that entail?

Comment: You can nest `Module` within `Manipulate` (and I think nesting it the other way around is what caused the syntax warning because the Manipulate did not play nice with the Module outside of it). Or as you said you can use `With`, and in this case it's acceptable to do so as `A` is basically just a constant that does not change its value when the code is run.

Comment: Is there some specific reason why the inverted order (i.e. `Module` inside the `Manipulate`) is preferable?

Comment: I have no clue, but I'd like to add that if you nest `Module` within `Manipulate`, your `Module` variables can depend on the manipulate parameter, whereas you cannot achieve this the other way around (as the manipulate parameter disappears outside of the scope of the Manipulate block). You can try this to see what I'm talking about: 'Manipulate[Module[{A = k}, Plot[A Sin[3 k x], {x, 0, 20}]], {k, 1, 10}]`. Of course in your case that's not going to be important since your Module variable does not change, hence the use of `With` will be just fine.

Comment: This is an issue for me as certain applications I'm using do need this. Note, however, that code of the form `Module[{A}, Manipulate[A = k; Plot[A Sin[k x], {x, 0, 20}], {k, 1, 10}]]` works fine in both v9 and v10, but only v10 colours it as incorrect syntax.

Comment: I think the point is that `A` (or rather the temporary variable `A$xxx` generated by `Module`, where `xxx` is some number) will be kept alive by the `Manipulate` even after returning from the `Module`. Now the variable won't go away as long as it is referenced, which I actually consider an useful feature (it allows you to implement closures). At least that's how it is in Version 8; one would hope that it didn't change in v10. Does v10 also mark the `v` in the following code red? `Module[{v=0},next[]:=v++]`

Comment: @celtschk [It doesn't](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7peLR.png). I only partially understand what you're saying. What would the code I posted, or similar code, be able to do that it wouldn't be able with a `With` instead of a `Module`.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the error class description (on second reading I'm no longer sure). Does the following give a red `v`? `Module[{v=1},Hold[v]]`? What about `Module[{v=1},v]`? And `Module[{v=1},v;0]`? And `Module[{v=1},Hold[v];0]`?

Comment: @celtschk none of those have red `v`s. The problem, as you suggested originally, is with expressions of the form `Module[{v}, Dynamic[v]]` where the Dynamic output would break the localization of the variable.

Comment: But then I don't understand why it wasn't made red in my original example: Try adding a Print statement like this to reveal the module's local variable name: `Module[{v=0},Print[Hold[v]];next[]:=v++]` and then evaluate the variable outside the module; you'll see it has still the value assigned in the module. The same is true for `Module[{v=1},Hold[v]]` (here you get the variable name right in the result, so no `Print` is necessary to reveal it). Also note that while the behaviour with `Block` and `Manipulate` is pretty bad, I don't see an issue with the corresponding `Module` behaviour; …

Comment: … indeed, exactly this "keeping alive" part is what allows you to implement closures using `Module`.

Comment: You are correct. Both versions allow the `$`'d variable to leak its value to the outside, but they are not coloured red. I'm unsure, then, of how (un)desirable this feature actually is. What exactly do you mean by "implement closures"?

Comment: See the section "Module"/"Advanced usage" in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/129) answer for an example of a closure. Anyway, after reading the documentation of `DynamicModule` I think I now figured out what the problem with Module+Manipulate probably is: Dynamic content (like `Manipulate`) is stored *across sessions*. However a normal `Module` variable is not stored that way. I guess that would create problems as soon as you save the notebook and later open it in a new instance of Mathematica.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on [Mr.Wizard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55128/1000) and [comments by Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55121/changes-to-colouring-in-mathematica-10#comment158477_55128) and [celtschk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/129/celtschk), I now understand that the code I posted does have undesirable side-effects and it should be avoided. Specifically, the scoping constructs [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) and [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) are meant to completely localize the variables in their first argument (for more information see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs)). However, placing their scoped variables inside a [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) (or other dynamic construct) can cause the values to leak, and this should be avoided - hence the syntax error marks.

> TL;DR:
>
> Behaviour of the form
>
> ```
> Block[{v}, Dynamic[v = 1]]
> v
>
> (*
> 1
> 1
> *)
> ```
>
> is unwanted. Scoping constructs which contain Dynamic objects like Manipulate should be replaced by [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) or [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html).

Modules localize their variables by creating new local variables that are unique for the session. Thus, inside `Module[{A}, ... ]`, the variable `A` gets replaced by a variable of the form `A$1234`, and this should not be accessible outside of the Module:

```
Module[{A},
 Print[A]; A = 1
 ]
(*
A$464
1
*)

A$464
(*
A$464
*)
```

Placing a `Manipulate` inside the `Module`, though, can cause this value to leak:

```
Module[{A},
 Print[A];
 Manipulate[A = k, {k, 1, 2}]
 ]
```

will produce e.g. `A$524` and the Manipulate, and then asking for that variable gives

```
A$524
(*
1
*)
```

`Block` is similar but slightly worse, as it is now the value of the scoped variable itself that can leak. The expected behaviour is

```
Block[
 {A},
 Print[A];
 A = 1
 ]
A
(*
A
1
A
*)
```

but with a `Manipulate` inside, the value of `A` *outside* the Block can change:

```
Block[{A},
 Print[A];
 Manipulate[A = k, {k, 1, 2}]
 ]
```

returns `A` and the Manipulate, and then asking for `A` returns

```
A
(*
1
*)
```

This is indeed incorrect and should be avoided.

The correct way to go about it, then, appears to be using a [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html) whenever there are dynamic objects inside the scoping construct. This type of Module is indeed capable of containing the side effects described above. Thus,

```
DynamicModule[{A},
 Print[A];
 Manipulate[A = k, {k, 1, 2}]
 ]
```

will produce e.g. `A$827` and the Manipulate, and now the scoped variable `A$827` is properly contained:

```
A$827
(*
A$827
*)
```

For further details about this, and about the differences between Module and DynamicModule, see [Advanced Dynamic Functionality - Module versus DynamicModule](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#877365235). For more on the behaviour of Module, Block and With in different circumstances, see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs).

Comment: Well done! Thanks for the great lesson.

Comment: Nice self answer. +1

Answer (score 8):

I believe that highlighting is there specifically to encourage you to use `DynamicModule` rather than `Module`:

```
DynamicModule[{A = 1}, Manipulate[Plot[A Sin[k x], {x, 0, 20}], {k, 1, 10}]]
```

One reference:

- http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Sep/msg00198.html

Also related:

- [Table function with Part[] call misbehaving, but only after initial startup of Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1669/121)

Comment: So the rule of thumb is to use `DynamicModule`s whenever there are `Dynamic`-like constructs like `Manipulate` inside?

Comment: `Manipulate` is evaluated in a special way, that I don't understand fully.  It is not actually evaluated, just formatted in a special way.  After creating a `Manipulate`, checking its InputForm shows that the head is still `Manipulate`.  Anyway, the point is that by the time the guts of Manipulate get evaluated, that variable `A` is not localized any more. ...

Comment: ...  For some reason, the `Manipulate` still seems to work as one would naively expect, but that's only because `A$1234` has leaked from Module and is not being cleared as it normally would.  To sum up: it looks like a very bad idea to use Module around Manipulate.