# Manipulate scoping issue?

Tags: manipulate, scoping

I'm running Mathematica 12.2 and have encountered the following unexpected behavior with Manipulate:

```
Block[{G},       
     G[x_]:=x;
     DynamicModule[{x}, 
        Manipulate[
            G[x],
            {{x, -1, "x"}, -1, 1, Appearance->"Labeled"}
     ]]]
```

I anticipate Manipulate will recognize the definition of G and so will show the value of x.
It does not. G is unevaluated.  Without the surrounding Manipulate, G is evaluated. Without the surrounding Block, G is evaluated. Without the DynamicModule, G is evaluated. Bug? Am I missing something?

Comment: When the `Block` evaluates it returns a `DynamicModule`, and at that point all definitions you have given to `G` are gone.  Why not use something like `DynamicModule[{G, x}, G[x_] := .....]`?

Comment: If I use the menu command Help > Why the coloring?... then I get a dialog that there is an "order of evaluation conflict" with `G`.  Not a complete explanation, but it is what @JasonB. is pointing out.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55121/syntax-highlighter-shows-error-for-manipulate-when-its-inside-a-block-or-a-modu -- And this: https://groups.google.com/g/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/c/XcLM5xDRqHE/m/V0FghIKeO_QJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `InputForm` to examine the output of your code, not just how it formats:

```
(*In*)
InputForm @ Block[{G},
    G[x_] := x;
    DynamicModule[{x}, Manipulate[G @ x, {{x, -1}, -1, 1}]]
]

(*Out*)
DynamicModule[{x}, Manipulate[G[x], {{x, -1}, -1, 1}], DynamicModuleValues :> {}]
```

You see that the `Block` evaluated and returned a `DynamicModule`, as should be expected.  The definition of `G` has evaporated along with the `Block`.  Look at what we get switch the `Block` to `Module`:

```
DynamicModule[{x}, Manipulate[G$4159[x], {{x, -1}, -1, 1}], DynamicModuleValues :> {}]
```

Here the scoped variable escaped the `Module` and keeps its definition, so this now works.

I think the best route to go is to localize `G` in the `DynamicModule`:

```
In[2]:= InputForm @ DynamicModule[{G}, G[x_] := x; Manipulate[G@x, {{x, -1}, -1, 1}]]

Out[2]//InputForm=
DynamicModule[{G}, Manipulate[G[x], {{x, -1}, -1, 1}], 
 DynamicModuleValues :> {{DownValues[G] = {HoldPattern[G[x_]] :> x}}}]
```